# Re-writing JS code to React - classList.toggle

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, onclick

I would like to re-use my JS code from old app to my new - but the new one is using React instead of just Vanilla JS.

My goal is to transition/animate nav menu and nav menu items in mobile version.

I tried to re-write it JSX compatible, but I am still getting an error - **TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null**

This is the code which should trigger opening the burger nav menu and transition/animate them.

```
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const navMenu = document.querySelector('.nav-menu');
    const navMenuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-menu li');

    const handleClick = () => {
        burger.classList.toggle('active');
        navMenu.classList.toggle('open');
        navMenuItems.forEach((item, index) => {
            if (item.style.animation) {
                item.style.animation = '';
            } else {
                item.style.animation = `0.3s ease-in slideIn forwards ${
                    index * 0.1 + 0.3
                }s`;
            }
        });
    };
```

And basic trigger onClick -  `<div className="burger" onClick={handleClick}>`

How can it be adjusted that I won't get the error anymore and achieve the same thing ?

Comment: const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const navMenu = document.querySelector('.nav-menu');
    const navMenuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-menu li');
can you check whether you getting any value in const.
Ideally you use ref in such condition

Comment: I do get the value in console - it is the whole html class. So works just fine.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the live code on code pen?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-wood-zsnxj?file=/src/App.js Here you go.

Comment: I am not getting error in above mentioned code

Comment: Sometimes it does work but most of the time it's crashing. I dont know why. I need to have it fully working.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your code a bit to make it work with react

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.scss';

export default function App() {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  const navAnimation = () => {
    const navMenuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-menu li');
    navMenuItems.forEach((item, index) => {
      if (item.style.animation) {
        item.style.animation = '';
      } else {
        item.style.animation = `0.3s ease-in slideIn forwards ${index * 0.1 +
          0.3}s`;
      }
    });
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsActive(!isActive);
    navAnimation();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <nav>
        <div className="logo">LOGO</div>

        <ul className={isActive ? 'nav-menu open' : 'nav-menu'}>
          <li>why omni</li>
          <li>home office</li>
          <li>journal</li>
          <li>about us</li>
          <li className="globe-icon" />
          <li>get started</li>
        </ul>

        <div className={isActive ? 'burger active' : 'burger'} onClick={handleClick}>
          <div className="top-line" />
          <div className="middle-line" />
          <div className="bottom-line" />
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Demo** : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9qimbx)

Comment: Thank you! - it did resolved the error, but now I have some styling issues that does not match my previous style.

Comment: The style of which element?

Comment: the burger menu should transition when opened and it's also not closing properly.

Comment: Thank you @MB_ ! It's still does not close the white background when clicking on closing menu after transition - but I can take it from here, get the logic! thanks